# Rails: gem.config & rake gems:install -- no such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to use config/environment.rb to install a ruby gem dependency (because I don't have sudo access to our server; ergo, can't just call `gem install hpricot`).

I've tried including sundry arguments (`:version`, `:source`, `:lib`) but I still get `rake aborted! no such file to load -- hpricot`

**Update:** It turns out that when I remove the plugin which requires hpricot, then I can execute `rake gems:install` successfully. But that's not very helpful. It means that if I ever move my app, I run into a problem of being unable to rake its gems (because I will have reinstalled the plugin and added features that depend on it).

How is this supposed to work?

**Sys:** WinXP, Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake gems:install` has been deprecated because it never really worked. You can imagine having a gem installer with dependencies to the very gems it's trying to install is a bad idea.

It's advisable to use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) instead if that's an option.

Bundler allows you to install gems to any destination you want, something specifically intended to side-step the whole "requires `sudo`" problem you describe. It's often as easy as this:

```
bundle install --path ~/my_gems/
```

You can make your Rails 2.3.x application use Bundler by following [a few simple steps](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html) and from there your life will be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks. Our IT director told me we just don't have bundler installed (as though he had no inclination to add it). Any workaround?

Comment: The best workaround is to install it. You can install gems at the user level using a tool like [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). How hard can it be for someone to do: `gem install bundler` anyway?

Comment: Righto. I asked IT, and they said they'd rather just install the gem I wanted (hpricot). So that's what they did. (roll eyes)

Answer (score 2):

Rails is trying to load the gem before executing the rake task. This is a known issue with rails 2.x. The only solution I know of is to switch to using bundler to manage gems or manage then manually.

Bundler can be used with rails 2 but it requires some modifications to your application and deployment scripts. This is a good place to start: http://gembundler.com/rails23.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned to @tadman, we don't have bundler installed (and clearly I can't install it). Maybe I should press our IT director to install it. But do you have a workaround?