# no such file to load -- redis-namespace

Tags: namespaces, redis, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working on `Rails 2.3.8`. I have following in my `environment.rb`

```
config.gem "redis"
config.gem "redis-namespace", :lib => "redis/namespace"
```

When I list my redis gems then I see:

```
redis (2.0.3)
redis-namespace(0.7.0)
```

When I run `rake gems:install` then I get an error that says:

```
no such file to load -- redis-namespace
```

Shouldn't requiring "redis/namespace" solve the issue? Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: rails 2.3.8 or 3.2.8? :)

Comment: one more thing. If I was using rails 3.2.8, I would not be using environment to set the gems.. rather I would be using GemFile! :) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if `rake gems:install` depends on the very gem it is trying to install.

Try using [`rails_gem_install`](http://sleeplesscoding.blogspot.com/2010/07/install-rails-apps-dependencies-where.html) or [`bundler`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067457/rails-gem-config-rake-gemsinstall-no-such-file-to-load) instead.